# I am trying to write to ini files in Delphi but I keep getting errors

Tags: delphi, ini

Here is my code for writing to the ini file.

```
 Ini := TIniFile.Create(ChangeFileExt('StudentALevelMathsTracker.exe','.ini')) ;
 try
   Ini.WriteString('Settings', 'FilePath', edtFilePath.text);
   Ini.UpdateFile;
 finally
   Ini.Free;
 end;
```

However when I run this I get an error saying

> Project ALevelMathsTracker.exe raised exception class EIniFileException with message 'Unable to write to studentALevelMathsTracker.ini'

Is this a problem with the network I'm on or my code?

Comment: Why did you change the extension of an exe to .ini?

Comment: I was following the advice given by this webpage http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/tinifile.htm , and before I did that it appeared to be writing to the file but it wouldn't read.

Comment: I am running the application on my College network. Will that be a big problem when working with ini files?

Comment: You did **not** follow the advice in the given link `TIniFile.Create(ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName,'.ini')) ;`. You can retrieve the application name also with `ParamStr(0)` => `TIniFile.Create( ChangeFileExt( ParamStr(0), '.ini' ) );`. Both will return the **full path** to the exename. But take care if you have write permission in the application folder

Comment: Well, I guess the error message is pretty clear! The question is, where is the ini-file supposed to be stored? It seems you don't have the right permissions to write to that location.

Comment: `ChangeFileExt('StudentALevelMathsTracker.exe','.ini')` is rather pointless. You can replace it with `'StudentALevelMathsTracker.ini'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TIniFile` is a thin wrapper around the PrivateProfile API.

If you do not specify a full path, the API creates the .ini file relative to the OS system folder, which you likely do not have write access to.

If you base the filename on `Application.ExeName` or `ParamStr(0)`, you are creating the .ini file relative to your app's folder, which you likely do not have write access to, especially if the app is installed under `Program Files`.

What you should do is use `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_APPDATA)` or similar API to get the path to tbe user's AppData folder, create your own subfolder under it, and then create your .ini file in that subfolder.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should be making variables, so you yourself can read what is going on:

```
procedure TForm1.MyProc;
var
  Ini:TIniFile;
  FileName: string;
begin
  // probably can not write to this directory:
  //FileName :=  ChangeFileExt('StudentALevelMathsTracker.exe','.ini');
  FileName := 'c:\afolder_i_have_permission_to_write_to\StudentALevelMathsTracker.ini';

  Ini := TIniFile.Create(FileName) ;
 try
   Ini.WriteString('Settings', 'FilePath', edtFilePath.text);
   Ini.UpdateFile;
 finally
   Ini.Free;
 end;
end;
```

Once you have a variable named FileName, you can inspect it in the debugger, if the path where it is being written to can not be written to because it is not a location that the current user has write priveleges to, then the change above makes sense. However, since I suspect you are running inside the IDE, the problem may be something else.

Having the variable makes the value you pass into TIniFile easier to inspect and makes the logic you intended to write clearer to YOU, which makes the solution (the change to your code) more obvious to YOU.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem, and found that WriteString internally calls `WritePrivateProfileString` and if the result is false then it raises the `EIniFileException` which effectively hide the true cause of the failure.

So you can wrap your code in a `Try Except` block and call `RaiseLastOsError` to show the error that windows was trying to alert you to.

This will help in tracking down the problem of such an error.

```
try
  Ini.WriteString('Settings', 'FilePath', edtFilePath.text);
  Ini.UpdateFile;
except
  on EIniFileException do
  begin
    // This will raise an EOSError Exception with a better message.
    RaiseLastOsError;
  end;
end;
```